# Difference among ruby gems, npm packages, and yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, npm-install

When I start a new Rails project, it gives me a template with a few different files for packages: Gemfile, package.json, and yarn.lock. I'm trying to understand if all three of these packages work together, or if I'm supposed to choose one. For example, in my Gemfile, I can add 'jquery-rails' but is this the same as installing jQuery to my package.json file? I'm having trouble understanding the difference between running bundle install and npm install.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short it looks like this:

In Ruby, the `bundler` analyzes the list of libraries (gems) specified in the `Gemfile`, builds a dependency tree and fixes it in `Gemfile.lock`, downloads gems from different sources

In JS, various managers do the same: `npm`, `yarn`, `bower`, etc. By default Rails use `yarn`. They download all libraries to `node_modules` folder

`package.json` is analogue of `Gemfile` (but more advanced, for example you can define command line scripts there). `yarn.lock` is analogue of `Gemfile.lock`

Thus, `bundler` for Ruby and `yarn` / `npm` for JS libraries

Answer (score 2):

`Gemfile` is to manage ruby gems, while `package.json` and `yarn.lock` for js packages.
The good thing about installing jQuery via `jquery-rails` is that will allow you to easily integrate jQuery into a Rails project, regardless what asset manager you're using it.
On the other hand, installing jQuery using npm/yarn allows you to upgrade the package directly from the original repo, without having an intermediary (`jquery-rails` in this case) that eventually could have the gem unattended (as now that they're using jquery 3.6.0 while the last one is 3.6.1).
Personally, I'd choose the 2nd option, mostly because in general is a good practice to have these js/ruby worlds working separately, but the other reason is because any other js library you eventually will need it, probably will follow the same steps as installing jQuery, so it's not really a big deal integrating it with Rails in this way.